# Python - Assign the closest string from List A to List B based on Levenshtein distance - (ideally with pandas)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, levenshtein-distance

As introduction, I am pretty new to python, I just know how to use pandas mainly for data analysis.

I currently have 2 lists of 100+ entries, **"Keywords"** and **"Groups"**.

I would like to generate an output (ideally a dataframe in pandas), where for every entry of the list **"Keywords"**, the closest entry of the list **"Groups"** is assigned, using the **levenshtein distance** method.

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from editdistance import eval as levenshtein
import pandas as pd

keywords = ["foo", "foe", "bar", "baz"]
groups = ["foo", "bar"]

assigned_groups = [min(groups, key=lambda g: levenshtein(g, k))
                   for k in keywords]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Keyword": keywords, "Group": assigned_groups})
#   Group Keyword
# 0   foo     foo
# 1   foo     foe
# 2   bar     bar
# 3   bar     baz
```

Using [`editdistance`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/editdistance). Get it with `pip install editdistance`.

Note that this algorithm is `O(mn)`, where `m` is the length of the keywords and `n` the length of the groups.